# Best way of updating XPages Extension Library, so that developers and server are on the same release

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

Last week we encountered some issues in a Notesdatabase, because me and my collegue developer were not on the same version of the extension library.

What is the best procedure to make sure we're on the same version? I hope this can be done as follows:
 1. Add the latest version of updateSiteOpenNTF.zip in the updatesite.nsf (meaning: just adding it, it will automatically use the latest version, right?)
 2. Restart http on the servers
 3. Update in Designer via updatesite.nsf
... but I'm afraid we need the updateSitenOpenNTF-designer.zip as a developer, and we need to point to the local filesystem for this.

Any suggestions?

Important notice: we only use XPages for our webapplications, not in the Notes client.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update Domino Designer using the updatesite.nsf that you have added to your servers.

Use File - Application - Install in Domino Designer. From the Install/Update dialog select "Search for new features to install". On the next dialog select the button to add a remote location, and add the URL to your updatesite.nsf (`http://yourserver/updatesite.nsf`).

See the readme.pdf in the Extension Library zip file.

Comment: Hendrik, thanks for your answer.  I know I can use the updatesite.nsf; I just wonder if updateSiteOpenNTF.zip is sufficient as the general library for both server and designer. Any idea?

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten >Yes, it is sufficient. - so I wonder, why are there two update sites with quite different size?

Comment: Good questio, Frantisek. I am sure I have used a server updatesite.nsf to update my Domino Designer before. Someone should test this again :-)